# (MongoDB) database structure for Q&Answer website

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm trying to make a website similar to Yahoo & Answer or StackOverflow (different category, no competition), and I'm stuck at this point, I'll really appreciate any guidance from you guys as I'm very new to MongoDB.

I'm using Express framework on Node.js and MongoDB by the way.

The problem is to find the most efficient way to structure the database for users and questions/answers data.

Currently, there is a Questions model, inside there's a document for each category. Each document contains the question itself, the answers, and other info as described below:

```
math{
    OpenQuestions{
        'x+2=5, whats x?' : {
            asker: 'peter',
            likes: 12,
            answers: {
                'x is 3' : {
                    answerer: 'john',
                    likes: 25
                },
                'x is 2' : {
                    answerer: 'MATHSUX',
                    likes: 0
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    ClosedQuestions{
        //same as OpenQuestions
    }
}
```

In this way it's very easy to display the questions as we can easily retrieve questions based on the object's creation time and fetch them accordingly on the main question page.

**However**, if an user wants to see the questions he has asked, the only way I can think of is going through each `subject.OpenQuestions.QuestionItSelf.asker`, and check if it's the user himself, then fetch all the object matches for this username, it would be an immense calculation. I'm sure there exists a much better way, what do you all think?

Comment: I think it is safe to say you are going to have more than 16meg of document per subject, so don't embed

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has a limit of 16MB per document. Also, MongoDB doesn't behave very well when you have documents which grow in size. For performance reasons, MongoDB tries to keep a document in a contiguous section on the hard drive, so when a document grows, the hard drive space needs to be reallocated constantly.

For these reasons, it is not a good idea to store all questions in a single document.

It would be better to create a collection of questions and have a separate document for each question. To increase search performance, you can create some appropriate [indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/).

**By the way**: I am not sure if MongoDB is the right tool for your project. Your application sounds very relational and not like it can benefit from the document-oriented concept of MongoDB. On the other hand, your hierarchical way of thinking sounds more in tune with the [Redis](http://redis.io/) philosophy. But that's just a subjective opinion.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a bad idea to have the question as a key.  Make a `question` attribute and have the value of that attribute be the text of the question.  MongoDB does not have much in the way of tools to query on key values.  Pretty much all you have is `$exists` and that doesn't even support wildcards.  Do the same thing for each answer, instead of having the text of the answer be a key, have an `answer` key and have the value be the text of the answer.

Next, there's no reason to keep all your questions as sub-documents.  You can move the status to an attribute of the document (status: 'open' or status: 'closed' or status: 'answered but not closed' for example).  If you need to pre-compute the status at all that is - it might make more sense to have the answers as sub-documents and then you can derive the status based on the status of the answers (i.e. if a question doesn't have any answers then it's displayed as unanswered, if it has answers but none are marked as the solution then it's answered but not solved, if it has an answer marked as solution then it's closed, etc.).

Then, have the subject be an attribute of the question as opposed to a collection for each subject.  If you do that then finding questions for an asker is as easy as

```
db.questions.find({asker: 'John'}, {question:1, _id:0})
```

That will display the text of all questions John has asked

Your final schema will be a questions collection with a document structure that looks like this:

```
    {
        question: 'x+2=5, whats x?'
        asker: 'peter',
        likes: 12,
        subject: 'math',
        answers: [
            { answer: 'x is 3', answerer: 'john', likes: 25, solution: true },
            { answer: 'x is 2', answerer: 'MATHSUX', likes: 0}
        ],
        status: 'solved'
    }
```